# How update TSL 1.0 to TLS 1.2 version in a macosx server

Tags: macos, server, tls1.0

I have the information to switch from Mac OS X Server TLS 1.0 to TLS 1.1. But I do not know what file to add.

"
SSLProtocol -all -SSLv2 -SSLv3 -TLSv1 +TLSv1.1 +TLSv1.2

SSLHonorCipherOrder on

SSLCompression Off

SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW:-SSLv2:-SSLv3:-EXP:!kEDH
"

What files do I need to attach these settings to?

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest Server app version 5.3. It supports TLS v1.2 and has dropped TLS 1.0, so it should give you all you need.

For a discussion of the relevant config files, also see my question [tlsv1 alert protocol version when connecting via SSL to OS X Server](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280143/tlsv1-alert-protocol-version-when-connecting-via-ssl-to-os-x-server%20for%20more%20information), although it does not give an ultimate answer to which of the files are actually used.